# Servicestack server sent events - email application

Tags: c#, servicestack, email, server-sent-events

Can anyone guide me, where to find servicestack server sent event sample code.

First I explain my issue. I have created a restful service(using servicestack framework) to pull down list of emails for inbox folder using afterlogic mailbee object(external product). Now, each time if I do a pull, it takes more time to load list of emails because I am pulling down message body too.

Now I want to send down list of message headers first in the service, and then want the message body to load, because it take more time to pull down from imap object. I see server sent event is the only option here. If someone has a better solution for this, please suggest.

Now, if I have to use servicestack server sent events, I am unable to get any sample code, which I can look upon to implement in my case.

Please ask, if there is more clarification needed in my question.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample for your requirement.
It is called [Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat) (it uses [SSE](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)).

Otherwise another project called [EmailContacts](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts) can help you to develop the email app.

Answer (score 0):

[Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events) is to enable server/push real-time communication, if you want to optimize page loads you should separate your calls into 2 Services:

1. Fetch absolute minimum to render page
2. Fetch full details on demand